# Problemas con el DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, while, datatable

Estoy utilizando la librería DataTable y esta funciona bien hasta el momento de utilizar un ciclo while en el php ya que aunque me muestra todo, sin ningún error las funciones como buscar no funcionan ya que solo busca en el primer registro,aquí el código:

```
<table class="display" id="tabla">
        <thead>
            <button id="mostrar_agregar">Añadir</button>
            <tr class="edit_table"> 
                <th>Nombre del ingreso</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Descripción del ingreso</th>
                <th>Fecha del ingreso</th>
                <th>agregar</th>
                <th>eliminar</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
              $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$ingresos);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){?>

            <tbody>         
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["nombre_ingreso"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["valor_ingreso"]; ?></td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>   
        <?php } ?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa que el ciclo while debe estar abajo del `tbody` porque como lo tienes actualmente genera el tbody por cada ciclo que hace.

Debe estar de está forma

```
<table class="display" id="tabla">
      <thead>
          <tr class="edit_table"> 
             <th>Nombre del ingreso</th>
             <th>Valor</th>
             <th>Descripción del ingreso</th>
             <th>Fecha del ingreso</th>
             <th>agregar</th>
             <th>eliminar</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>

            <?php
                 $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$ingresos);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
             ?> 

          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["nombre_ingreso"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["valor_ingreso"]; ?></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>   
        <?php } ?>
       </tbody>
</table>
```